# android null excpetion when starts the activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

First of all

```
I am using support libraries
```

I have a BrowseFoods activity

```
<activity
      android:name=".BrowseFoods"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.Syriatel.BROWSEFOODS" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.app.searchable"
          android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value=".MainCustomerMenu2" />
</activity>
```

and the code for it is :

```
public class BrowseFoods extends ActionBarActivity{
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        int currentTab = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        if (currentTab == 0) {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_food, menu);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuItem);
                SearchManager searchManager =
                        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
                android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

                searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                        searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

            }
        } else {
            menu.clear();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.favoritefood, menu);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

In that actiivty I add two fragments as **tabs** , so when prepare for menu, i check which tab is currently used. Thus, i know which menu I have to use.

Please look at code, I am using **all_foods** menu
which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/searchMenuItem"
          android:title="searchnNsNNN"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"
          yourapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

when I run my application, I got this exception:

```
02-17 11:09:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 11:09:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5064): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-17 11:09:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5064):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-17 11:09:38.384: E/AndroidRuntime(5064):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
```

#### Note

If i comment these codes

```
 // searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                 //       searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
             //   searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

**the program works perfectly.**

Please help

Comment: Out of memory decoding your LinearLayout background image inflated in AllFoods2.java:64 - just make the background bitmap smaller

Comment: also should it not be `yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />`

Comment: @laalto if the problem with the image, why when i remove those lines, the program works perfectly and i can see the icon on the action bar pelase?

Comment: @user2059935 The specific point of OOM depends on your memory usage. When you comment out code that does allocations, there will be less memory used and the OOM is not triggered. In any case, the background bitmap is too large.

Comment: @Raghunandan you are the cleverest person on the word, I LIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIKE you. you are my God. please write an answer to accept it

Comment: @user2059935 i guess you may need to scale down the image also.

Comment: @Raghunandan which image please?

Comment: @user2059935 is your problem solved? if you are using a large image as a background then you would need to scale them down.

Comment: @Raghunandan the problem is completely solved, thank you very very very very much. but i am not using any background, i mean the only image in my action bar is the one with `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock` and this is very small image comes with the platform, right?

Comment: @user2059935 yes its belongs to the drawable in the android framework no need for any scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

to

```
  yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Reference: Look at adding Action Views @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

`OutOfMemory` generally occurs when you are trying to use large image. You run out of memory leading to OOM.

If you run into such a error make sure you scale down the image.